# How much precious metals and rare earth elements would be in a giant robot?

Tags: technology, materials, robots, metals

I was looking up the amount of precious metals like gold and silver and rare earth elements in a cell phone and was surprised to find out that an average iPhone contains [0.034 g of gold and 0.34 g  of silver](http://bbc.com/future/article/20161017-your-old-phone-is-full-of-precious-metals), which means that a tonne of iPhones contain 300 times more gold than a ton of gold ore and 6.5 times more silver than a ton of silver ore according to the linked article (along with other important metals such as platinum, palladium, neodymium, yttrium, etc.).

This got me wondering **how much precious metals and rare earth elements would be required to make a giant mecha work**, specifically a mecha that is implied to run using technology comparable to what we have now like Mechagodzilla from the recent *Godzilla versus King Kong* movie or the Jaegers in *Pacific Rim*. That is, the mecha isn't implied to use some novel branch of plot-related physics like the Minovsky Particle in Gundam. Ignore for the sake of the argument the fact that a giant robot would almost have to use exotic materials or physics in order to be able to move or a tactically viable weapon. **Specifically I'm wondering if the amount of rare earth metals to build such a robot would be enough to bankrupt most country's economies or turn a fallen mech into a potential goldmine as people scramble to scavenge the gold, silver, copper, etc. from it to sell elsewhere.**

For the sake of making this question more answerable, lets assume the robot is about 80 m (260 feet) tall, about the same size as Gipsy Danger from Pacific Rim. I don't have a detailed schematic of what this theoretical robot would look like, and I'm not sure any exists for any fictional mecha that would give a detailed approximation of how much of the robot would be computing systems rather than hydraulics or plating, so I'm only trying to figure out a very, very rough estimate. Possibly something like a modern warship could be used as an approximation.

Comment: The amount of revaltivly cheap things like steel, titanium, aluminium & copper alone would already probably be enough to make it a very valuable piece of scrap.

Comment: An open pit gold mine might be able to mine gold grades of around 3.4 g/t, but not 0.034 g/t. On this basis an iPhone would contain 1/100 the amount of of gold in a tonne of gold ore in a open pit mine, not 300 times. For an underground mine, the grade would have to be at least 7 g/t.

Comment: You are grossly underestimating the gold contents of gold ore. And rare earth metals are not actually rare or expensive. ("Earth" is the pre-chemical term for what today we call an "oxide". The "rare earths" were called rare in comparison with abundant oxides such as rust.

Comment: All you need to do to estimate this is to extrapolate from fighter jets (which do contain a lot of rare earth material).

Comment: Real metals and alloys are not nearly strong enough to support the kinds of forces involved in the way mechs are typically shown moving about. Are you really limiting yourself to real life elements and alloys? Some kind of fictional alloy or element would be necessary and so you could fiat that this fictional material is as rare and expensive as you would like.

Comment: 5g per ton is economically viable to mine. I assume that you haven't checked your figures.

Comment: The article you linked stated that a *ton* of iPhones contain 300 times the gold that a ton of gold ore contains, which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: So, before your world builds mecha, maybe they should build resource extraction bots in order to get the resources to waste them on killing people/things.

Comment: Fix your math: "** 0.034 g of gold and 0.34 g of silver, which is 300 times more gold than a ton of gold ore** is **enormously** inaccurate. A good gold ore contains about 14g/tonne, the very best is about 45g/tonne. Your statement is **wrong by a factor of TWO AND A HALF MILLION TIMES**

Comment: Actually, I've found the error.  The article that YOU quote from states (inaccurately, but in the right ballbark), "One **tonne** of iPhones would deliver 300 times more gold than a tonne of gold ore".. Unless you believe that an average iPhone weight one tonne?

Comment: VTC for basing the question upon false data, then failing to either adjust the question or delete it on being shown the falsehood.

Comment: P.S. if that article was truthful, it would have stated "One tonne of iPhones would deliver 18 times more gold than a tonne of gold ore".  18 times, not 300 times.  But that at least is only 1 order of magnitude off.

Comment: @PcMan Dude, I only just checked Worldbuilding SE two minutes ago. How could I have "failed to adjust the question" when I only just now saw your comment. Your comment saying VTC was submitted *seven minutes* after you made the comment saying the data was wrong, giving me no time to fix the question even if I did happen to be on SE at the time. And how am I supposed to the iPhone tonne thing is "false data" if those are the first references that come up when one looks for the amount of precious metals in electronics? Your comments are overly aggressive and confrontational, please calm down.

Comment: @PcMan I haven't been on Worldbuilding SE for three days. I have a day job and hence haven't had time to check Worldbuilding SE in detail.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the design of the mech, if it uses the equivalent of a smartphone for its control system then it needs a smartphones worth of gold.

Answer (score 18):

**Consider that a modern navy has warships which far exceed the mass of a giant mecha**

A modern aircraft carrier weighs in at between 50-100,000 tons, can be over 300 metres in length and require all kinds of precious minerals including one or more nuclear reactors. On top of that, modern bulk carriers are now hauling close to *half a million tons*. A commercial carrier could carry ten Gipsy Dangers in it's hold.

If it is pure materials you are thinking about, any modern nation could muster enough to build a giant mech the same way they build ships. The bulk of the materials will be relatively basic alloys, the only limitation is tech - the most complicated & advanced components of which are extremely small by comparison. Nearly all of the cost would be front-loaded r&d, if a practical design is cracked then there is no practical resource barrier to construction.

Comment: Good answer. I like to start worldbuilding by thinking about similar things in the real world. The fact that aircraft carriers exist is mindblowing if you think about it. We've built entire cities, complete with airports, that can travel pretty quickly around the world.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza Entire *floating* cities. I don't know if that's less or more impressive than other forms of travel, no matter, its mind blowing.

Comment: Tbh, I think we totally could build a giant mech right now, but it would be on the scale of developing an aircraft carrier from scratch, which means that nobody will do it without thinking it absolutely necessary

Answer (score 17):

**Not much**

Gold and silver would be mostly used in the electronics as where most of the giant robot would be armour plating, motors, pistons and the frame.

Your biggest value would be the steel, titanium, aluminium and copper.

Comment: Yes, a modern datacenter would have 10-100 times more gold in it. The only other potentially valuable component is the batteries, but this depends on how they are made. You might get a ton of expensive nickel out of it, but you might also get nothing valuable if they use lithium-iron chemistry.

Comment: @csiz Even if they're lithium-ion or LiFePO₄ or lead-acid, the batteries themselves would be pretty valuable, though--as batteries, not as their constituent elements. That's a lot of energy storage--think electric car battery times a few hundred at the minimum.

Comment: Yep - a giant robot only needs a tiny brain, at least by the standards of electronics today.  A single RaspberryPi with a suitable RTOS could easily control a massively complex robot with not much more than a bit of extra I/O.  We're talking trace amounts - a few dollars max - worth of rare materials.   The rest is just steel and other base materials.

Comment: Don't underestimate the value of the steel, titanium, aluminum, and copper.  A very ballpark estimate is that an 80-meter-tall mecha would have a scrap value of a million dollars just for the bulk materials.

Comment: If the robot runs on fossil fuels and has a catalytic converter (nice of it to take care of the environment as it destroys the city) it may have tens or hundreds of thousands of dollars worth of rhodium and platinum.

Comment: given that its worth recovering precious metals from mobile phones i'd think it would be from a multi tonne robot

Comment: I suspect that the salaries of the people designing and building that thing would be worth orders of magnitude more than the materials in the robot.

Answer (score 3):

**Powerful computers**

I'm assuming the only real difficulty you face is controlling all the parts correctly to get the mecha to function. The great part is, you don't need enormous amounts. Our current computing power is massive. We're still working on the programming for efficient movement and such, but the power is already there. We can look at the [robotics devision](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uhND7Mvp3f4) to see we only need further enhancements in AI. They have smaller processors in general and can already accomplish much. For the precious metals you wouldn't need more than an average or high end computer. Likely even less. This isn't a whole lot more precious metals than in current phones.

You do need copper for the wiring and cooling, but with the billions of kilometers of wiring everywhere, from electrified tracks to buildings to your phones, an army of mecha's won't make much of a difference.

**The mech**

As you say, the worth is in the construction itself. A large mecha needs very special materials to stay standing, as well as good power supplies. This is either high powered fuel, or something like nuclear power. That means it isn't the precious metals you refer to in the text, like gold, silver and palladium that will be depleting your countries resources. It'll be the special construction materials of the mechcas well as their mode of power. Exotic alloys of titanium, specially formed carbon nanotubes or whatever. These will make the bulk of the mecha and make it expensive. Copper is incredibly cheap compared to that.

Comment: I almost deleted my answer after *actually* reading your answer, but then decided there are decent enough differences. Happy to hear differing opinions(i.e. "nah, its the same answer"), but +1 either way.

Answer (score 1):

Is the robot powered by AI?

Yes:
There's a decent amount, and maybe worth harvesting, harder to say. As other's have said, it's almost entirely cheap materials with a higher value "brain" - if controlling itself, interpreting its own environment, etc there's probably a super computer inside worth arguing for. While I don't think its likely (my best guess is our limitation is our algorithms more than our hardware), I don't think anyone could currently disprove an idea that you'd need the entire innards of an 80m mecha to actually achieve a computer capable of true, generalized, AI. This would certainly add a lot more precious metals, i.e. ~75 cubic meters of iphones, whatever that comes out to. Or maybe it's an AI using quantum computing, and the secret to quantum computing at relative normal temperatures is to happen inside a 2 ton gold block. If you'd like it to be valuable, I'd go into future tech that "happens" to require far more precious metals to accomplish than anything currently does.

No:
See other answers - the base materials will be so many orders of magnitude greater, and easier to harvest in a usable way, they'll far exceed the value of the gold or rare earth elements.